# Apple store connect review not available

Tags: ios

We have submitted our app for review, and after getting feedback from Apple Review and fixing a few issues, our app does not have the submit for review button anymore, only Save.

Another thing is that since we added subscriptions they have been in "waiting for review" status for 5 days now, where the App store localization has a status of "Rejected". Whatever I try to change in the localization it throws an error

[image]

Comment: For account-related issues on an app store, contacting their support would be more suitable: https://developer.apple.com/support/